# Ubuntu Forums New Log-in?

Tags: users, ubuntu-forums

I registered back in '07.  Since that time I have changed email addresses.

The current re-registration scheme for a pre-existing account involves sending a confirmation number to the originally registered email account that I have abandoned due to Yahoo's *privacy* policy.

How do I communicate with the appropriate group so that I can log into the Ubuntu Forums?

Comment: Why don't you just register afresh?

Answer (score 1):

well if you have any problem with Ubuntu forums login then forum Moderators are ready to help you always and you can use any IRC client to join with them at `#ubuntuforums.`

If you would like to talk with them from the browser then you can do it from http://webchat.freenode.net/

hope that helps.